# Hebrew turn into junk when copied oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, intellij-idea, encoding

I tried to copy oracle version 11 database to version 12, some of the data there is in hebrew. The english data move correctly, but the data in hebrew is displayed as junk. When I log to the DB dirrectly all work fine(with hebrew), BUT when I log with intellij I see the junk with hebrew.

I checked for encoding, and both DBs have the same encoding.

Comment: What is the `NLS_CHARACTERSET` of both databases (assuming the data is stored in `char` or `varchar2` columns)?

Comment: iw8iso8859p8 both of them

Comment: What is the column data type? Can you add a screenshot, showing the problem? Also try to set the font, which is able to display Hebrew (which has all Hebrew glyphs) in Settings(Preferences) | Editor | Font page.

Comment: @Yagel are you able to write hebrew on the editor ? if no make sure in controle panel the language added is hebrew .. if yes what the nlslang in regeedit > oracle ? it should be ansi suported

Comment: Can you do a "select dump(column, 1016) from table ..." for a column where you are sure the characters are hebrew? 
This will show what the DB "means" it stores in this column/row. 
for details, please see the documentation: 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions048.htm#SQLRF00635